# Global Blue and getting validation when exiting EU by ferry

Tags: ferries, morocco, tax-refunds

I made some purchases in France, for which the store prepared tax refund forms; however, I am not leaving the EU from France. I will be leaving via ferry from Spain to Morocco.

Does anyone have experience finding a customs desk to validate the forms (which I can mail postpaid) at a non-airport site? Will it be obvious?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/183136/118049) :

> ... You have to get your documents stamped by a customs officer at the point of exit of the EU – not necessary in the same EU country where you bought it.

Since you're leaving EU from Spain :

[Agencia Tributaria](https://www.agenciatributaria.es/static_files/AEAT/Aduanas/Contenidos_Privados/Viajeros/Viajeros/Vers_ingles.pdf) states

> What SHOULD I DO if there are no interactive DIVA
> terminals at my exit point from Spanish territory,
> or **if my purchase was made in an EU Member
> State other than Spain?**
> Go to the customs services office.

You will absolutely find a customs office at the seaport, but you may need to check opening times of it before leaving

Comment: I asked one of the ferry companies, and they assure me that the relevant desk is easy to see.